# Flatlist crashes with one component but not with another

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using [react-native-socials](https://github.com/PierreCapo/react-native-socials) to display tweet data from a backend API, in a flatlist. I have implemented `pullToRefresh` and also refresh the feed, when we reach the end. But after a few update of the feed value, in turn the flatlist component, I see that there's a warning :

```sh
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

And the next time I update the flatlist it crashes stating that

```sh
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.created_at'
```

Whereas the same doesn't happen when I just use a `Text` component to render `data.created_at`.

Any suggestions/ideas why this might be happening or how do I solve this or how do I debug this

This is the flatlist code :

```js
~~~~ SNIP for brevity ~~~~
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in 2nd useEffect");
    loadFeed(typeOfFeed);
  }, [url]);

  const loadFeed = async (typeOfFeed) => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    console.log("url in loadFeed : " + url);
    let userData = await getAndRefreshToken();
    if (userData) {
      setUser(userData);
    }
    postsApi.setAuthToken(userData["idToken"]["jwtToken"]);
    const response = await postsApi.getPosts(typeOfFeed, url);
    if (response.ok) {
      if (response.data[0].id == feed[0]?.id) {
        ToastAndroid.show("No new posts", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      } else if (response.data?.length > 0) {
        if (typeOfFeed == postType.TWEET) {
          settCursor({
            next: response.headers.next,
            previous: response.headers.previous,
          });
        } else if (typeOfFeed == postType.ARTICLE) {
          setaCursor({
            next: response.headers.next,
            previous: response.headers.previous,
          });
        }
        setFeed(response.data);
        console.log("feed[0].id : " +feed[0].id + " response.data[0].id : " +response.data[0].id);
      }
    } else {
      ToastAndroid.show("No new posts", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      console.error(response.problem);
    }
    setRefreshing(false);
  };

~~~~~ SNIP ~~~~~~~
<FlatList
      ref={refContainer}
      data={feed}
      keyExtractor={(post) => {
        return post.id.toString();
      }}
      ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
      refreshing={refreshing}
      onRefresh={onRefresh}
      onEndReached={onEndReached}
      onEndReachedThreshold={onEndReachedThreshold}
    />
```

### Update

Here's the `renderItem` code :

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <View
    style={{
      padding: 10,
      borderRadius: 35,
      backgroundColor: colors.white,
    }}
  >
    {item.type == postType.TWEET && (
      // <Twitter useCustomTweetExtendedData={item.content} />
      <Text>
        {item.id}
        {"\n\n"}
        {item.content.created_at}
      </Text>
    )}
    {item.type == postType.ARTICLE && (
      <Card
        url={item.source_url}
        title={item.title}
        subTitle={item.description}
        imageUrl={item.content.image}
      />
    )}
    {ctf && <CTFCard ctf={item} />}
    {!ctf && (
      <CardFooter
        style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
        item={item}
        onPress={() => handleBookmark(item)}
      />
    )}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: can you share you `renderItem` function?

Comment: @B.Mohammad done.

Comment: where do use `data.created_at`?

Comment: It's not used by my code rather in the library react-native-socials , [here](https://github.com/PierreCapo/react-native-socials/blob/master/src/Twitter/api.ts#L28)

Comment: Have you registered you app: `the Twitter API is not open. It is needed that you register your app (free version) to the Twitter portal to be able to fetch Twitter posts.`

Comment: I am fetching tweets from my backend, where I've some tweets saved